# Kafka Streams KGroupedTable recovery

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Suppose an aggregation like:

```
stream.groupByKey
      .count()
      .toStream    
      .to(topic)
```

What happens after the default broker retention time e.g. 1 week has passed and the local state-store of the count operation has to be recovered? Will it loose the counts of those keys removed by retention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I missed the point that the changelog topic for count gets the configuration "cleanup.policy"="compact" which implicitly sets the retention to infinity. Therefore no keys will be removed due to retention.